# .NET 4.7 returning Tuples and nullable values

Tags: c#, tuples, .net-4.7

Ok lets say I have this simple program in .NET 4.6:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main()
        {
            var data = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetResults();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }

        private static Tuple<int,int> GetResults()
        {
            return new Tuple<int,int>(1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine. So with .NET 4.7 we have the new Tuple value type. So if I convert this it becomes:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main()
        {
            var data = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetResults();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }

        private static (int,int) GetResults()
        {
            return (1, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Great! Except it doesn't work. The new tuple value type is not nullable so this does not even compile.

Anyone find a nice pattern to deal with this situation where you want to pass a value type tuple back but the result could also be null?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By adding the nullable type operator `?` you can make the return type of the `GetResults()` function nullable:

```
private static (int,int)?  GetResults()
{
    return (1, 2);
}
```

Your code would not compile though because `async` is not allowed in the `Main()` function. (Just call another function in `Main()` instead)

---

**Edit**: Since the introduction of C# 7.1 (just a few months after this answer was originally posted), `async Main` methods are permitted.

Comment: How to call async methods from Main method: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/08/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-console-app-main-method/

Comment: What about form an anonymous lambda?